# Angular JS. Timeout modal hides behind the already opened modal

Tags: javascript, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am using angular JS.

I have an  an issue with a timeout modal. If on the gui, any modal already opened and time out modal comes up due to session inactive, the timeout modal hides behind the already opened modal. Need help here on how to get the timeout modal on the top of all the modals

Answer (score 0):

I assume, based on what you're saying,

> the timeout modal hides behind the already opened modal

this is a CSS issue. You can increase the `z-index` value of the modal element of your timeout modal. Here's a sample css rule in applying `z-index`.

```
#timeout-modal.modal-popup {
   z-index: 999;
}
```

for inline:

```
<div style="z-index:999;">[MODAL CONTENT]</div>
```

You can create a customizable modal pop-up directive in angular if you want you can have your modal element styled like this the angular way.

```
<div ng-style="timeoutZIndex">...</div>
```

In your scope you can have it like this:

```
$scope.timeoutZIndex = {
   'z-index': 999
}
```

Let me know if there's a need to clarify things more.

Comment: Thanks Carlo, my issue is fixed with your help. Just to update that I have to add "!important" so that it can override my changes.

<div style="z-index:999 !important"

Comment: I'm glad to be of help. :)